# For $n$ points $P_1$, $\ldots$, $P_n$ on the unit circle show that $\sum_{i<j} d(P_i, P_j )^2 ≤ n^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Suppose that $P_1$, $P_2$, . . . , $P_n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) are points on a circle of radius 1. For any two points $X$, $Y$ on the plane, let $d(X, Y)$ denote the standard Euclidean distance.
>
> Prove
> that $$\sum_{1≤i≤j≤n}
> d(P_i, P_j)^2 ≤ n^2$$
>
> and find when equality holds.

For this question initially my motivation was to search using the Pigeon Hole Principle, but then I realised I was on the wrong track. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the law of cosines? And basic dot products?

Comment: No.... How do we apply that

Comment: You edit your question to use law of cosines on that, and show me what you get.

Comment: On which will I apply law of cosines.  .@Ted Shifrin

Comment: Make an effort here. There’s only one answer to your question.

Comment: Now done... After that how do we get to the proof part@achille hui

Comment: Someone kindly help.... I don't get it... Why Mathsstack exchange is so irresponsive to people with lesser intellect... This is a Platform to learn.... See in AOPS.... We get to learn...here no-one will answer unless you know how to do it... Giving small hints which will lead you nowhere...

Comment: If you [edit] your question to show an attempt using the cosine law & dot product, like Ted suggested, then people may reverse their downvotes. BTW, begging for help or complaining that your question is being neglected is likely to attract downvotes on Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Check that
$$n(\sum_{i=1}^n \|v_i\|^2) - \|\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\|^2 = \sum_{i< j} \|v_i -v_j\|^2$$
for any vectors $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_n$.

$\bf{Added:}$ One checks the identity in dimension $1$ ( [Lagrange indentity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity)), and then use the fact $\|w\|^2= \sum w_s^2$, where $w_s$' are the the components of $w$.

We have equality if and only if the sum of the unit vectors $v_i$ is $0$ :  $\sum v_i = 0$.

Comment: Hey orangeskid... What to do after this.. I didn't get... Actually I am currently in class 10..so I take some time to understand all these...can you elaborate... So that I can get it

Comment: @Nintendi:  Show the above identity holds.  That will give you the inequality.  Yes, it uses vectors and dot products and such. If you are not familiar with that, try to read a bit about it online, it's not that hard.

Comment: OK.. Thanks....done